# Firebase cloud functions not executing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to create some firebase cloud functions and it doesnt seem to be going through. Im a little confused because based on what I read this should work.

Heres my code thats not writing or executing:

```
   //Custom master notification.
 exports.TrackMasterNotification = functions.database.ref('/'+DatabaseNode+'/GeneralMessage/Master')
    .onUpdate(event => {
        console.log("Processed new CUSTOM notification");
        //news has been created
        InitializeNotificationProcess();
        IdAndNotification.forEach(user => {
                //Should really find out which to send
               SendIOSNotification(user.NotificationId, event.data.val(), 'ping.aiff', 1, 3 );
               SendAndroidNotification(user.NotificationId, event.data.val(),"");
        });

    });
```

Firebase looks like this:

```
-Firebase project
 -Development
   - General Message
      - Master: "value"
```

Edit

```
const DatabaseNode = "Development";
```

Ive changed the ref to

```
ref('/{DatabaseNode}/GeneralMessage/Master')
```

Comment: What is the value of `DatabaseNode`? Can you show how you initialize it (or even better: reproduce the problem with a hardcoded path)?
 Also: how do you trigger the function?

Comment: I apologize for leaving that out. Ive included it

Comment: In his comment, Frank asked: "how do you trigger the function?".  Please post the code that updates `/Development/GeneralMessage/Master` or indicate if you are updating using the Firebase Console.  I also note that in your description of the database, there is a space in "General Message". Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the ref path looks wrong.  It should be:

```
/{databaseNode}/GeneralMessage/Master
```

Also, confirm that it fires when you update an element within that branch of the database since you are using **onUpdate**.

You should then be able to grab the **databaseNode** value by using:

```
const node = event.params.databaseNode;
```

Comment: Great to know! Although it still doesnt work even when i hard code the value of databaseNode. Should I not see the console.log value written out?

Comment: Do you see the function setup in Firebase at all?  What happens if you use an **onWrite** event instead? exports.trackMasterNotifications = functions.database
  .ref('/myDatabasePath')
  .onWrite(event => {});  This will fire events for create, update, and delete instead of just on updating the node in the database.